# Pure JavaScript Programming

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, ide

I'm diving into web development again (first time was an utter failure), and I have some pretty spectacular resources for learning both HTML5 and CSS3. What I want to begin studying next is JavaScript so I can have absolute control over my pages. But before I begin integrating JavaScript into my work, I'd like to use JavaScript solely as a programming language (with console I/O and basic programs) to familiarize myself first. What are the best tools for accomplishing this? Because thus far, I haven't found any browser/tool that approaches the simplicity of writing a source file, and clicking run like you might with a C++ program. Thanks.

Comment: I use Sublime Text 2 and open the file in a browser. ctrl-s in the editor and ctrl-r in the browser and you are running
Also jsfiddle.net is something I use daily

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Node.js is your best shot.

Node is used for:

- Server-side applications (Sails, Express, Socket.io)
- Various frontend-related scripting (Grunt, LESS)

Comment: Awesome. I love products that were based on or written by Google engineers. They always put out quality stuff.

Answer (score 1):

You can try Node.js, that allows you to run Javascript programs from commandline. Other than that, Javascript runs in a browser.

Answer (score 1):

I think JetBrains makes the best IDEs in the world.  Their support of JavaScript, HTML5, and CSS3 is first-rate.  I'd recommend looking at WebStorm as your IDE.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend jsfiddle.net which allows you to type and run code. I might also suggest codecademy.com which has a very good program to teach you javascript and many other languages as well. There is also a really simple part of there website called "codebits" where you can compile js, html, and css and play around. W3schools.com is also very helpful for reference.

Comment: w3schools is so full of mistakes that it is not a relevant reference.

Comment: I still find it extremely helpful

Answer (score 1):

If you are running windows, the Windows Scripting Host (WSH) can run both Visual Basic Scripting *and* JavaScript... with the JavaScript having full access to things.

Because Microsoft supprorted VB Script over JScript (their version of EMCAScript), it is difficult to find documentation, though it does exist.  I have a fair number of admin tools written in JScript.

Answer (score -1):

Because that's not how Javascript works. You can't read user input from console.

You can use any browser's development tools and write Javascript code line by line.